# How are input lines defined for I/0 statements?

Tags: io, fortran

I want to read some values from a file called `Input.txt`. The input file looks like this:

```
    1       2       3       4
    1       2       3       4
    1       2       3       4
    1       2       3       4
    1       2       3       4
    1       2       3       4
  ....
```

in total its 36 lines of 1,2,3 and 4s

then I use the following code to read from the file:

```
program outputtest
    implicit none
    double precision, allocatable, dimension(:) :: A,B,C,D
    integer :: counter,ii, ierror
    ierror=0
    counter=1
    open(39, action='read', name='input.txt', status='old')
    do
    read(39,100, IOSTAT=Ierror)
    100 Format(T8,I1)
    If (Ierror>0) then
            print *, 'error when reading'
            stop
    end if
    If (ierror<0) then
            print*, 'end of file reached'
            exit
    end if

    counter=counter+1
    end do
    If (.not.allocated(A)) ALLocate(A(counter))
    If (.not.allocated(b)) ALLocate(b(counter))
    If (.not.allocated(c)) ALLocate(c(counter))
    If (.not.allocated(d)) ALLocate(d(counter))
    do ii=1, counter-1
            read(39,110, IOSTAT=ierror) A(ii), B(ii), C(ii), D(ii)
            110 Format(T8, I4, T16, I4, T24, I4, T32, I4)
            If (ierror.neqv.0) exit
    end do
    close(39)
    write (*,120)  A
    write (*,120) B
    write (*,120) C
    write (*,120) D
    120 Format('result:', 1x,I2)


end program outputtest
```

The problem is now that the `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` are all equal to zero, i.e. my output is:

```
result: 0
result: 0
result: 0
....
```

This means that I do not read either from the correct lines or I make another mistake. I used in vim the option ruler to see what lines those entries are in and used those lines together with T. I created the file `Input.txt` by using tabs. What is my mistake?

Comment: For a simple well structured input file such as you show us I'd drop the format statement entirely and simply use list-directed input, something like `read(39,fmt=*, IOSTAT=ierror) A(ii), B(ii), C(ii), D(ii)`.  Precise formatting on reads is fragile, and it's entirely possible that your `i4` elements are aligned with series of spaces in the input file rather than spanning the digits.

Comment: I rolled back OP's most recent edit.  It materially changed the question and made the answer below irrelevant.  It also pointed out that the input file shown is not a good representation of the input file OP actually has.  I suggest OP asks a new question.

Comment: Thanks! By making me ask a new question I figured out the answer to my new question as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two things:

1. You don't do a `rewind` in your file. At first you read through the whole file to get the number of lines, but without a rewind, you start reading at the end -- which means nothing gets actually read into the arrays.
2. `read` with explicit formats is dangerous. You have to be really certain that the input file matches the format precisely. In your case, I'd to as @high-performance-mark suggested and use `fmt=*`. Your input file should easily be read automatically.

That's what I can gleam from a quick browse. See if that helps.

Comment: And the simple lesson: if one uses `iostat=` one should pay attention to the value returned.

Comment: Ok, if you recommmend not to use formatted reading, what would you use, if you only want to read one of the columns, i.e. only the column containg the 2's?

Comment: Depends on how certain I am of the input file's format. The less certain I am, the more I'd be inclined to read in all values regardless, and just ignore the ones I don't want. Now if the file has been written by a Fortran Program, and I know that programs `FORMAT` statement, then I'd really use that.

Comment: @IanH You are right, I have made it more explicit what I meant.